# JUnit | MockServer | RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, junit, resttemplate, spy

I have one service called `PostService`, which has instance variable called `connectionManager Autowired`.

Inside this `connectionManager` there is a one instance variable called `restTemplate Autowired.`

And in the configuration java file, object of `RestTemplate` is created with some logic.

**When I write a test case around it, and create a `MockRestServiceServer` with an expected URL and post method, and in return expect a response with some body. and when I execute a test case I don't get mocked response from this `mockedRestServiceServer`.**

As much, I can sense, this is because during test execution, a real object of rest template is created and mock server is not used to send mocked response.

can someone help me, how to overcome from this ?

```
class PostServie {

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionManager connectionManager;

    public void postMessage(String msg) {
    // some logic
    }

}
```

```
@Component
class ConnectionManager {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public String getToken(){
        ResponseEntity<String> response = this.restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
        //returns response.body() in string format
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(){
        // some logic and returns object of RestTemplate
    }

}
```

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class PostServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private PostMessageService postMessageService;

    @Resource(name="authServerRestTemplet")
    private RestTemplate authServerRestTemplet;

    private MockRestServiceServer mockedAuthServerRestTemplet;

    private final String requestToAuthServer ="grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ceapiClientId";

   @Before
    public void setUp() { 

    mockedAuthServerRestTemplet = 
    MockRestServiceServer.createServer(authServerRestTemplet);

    }

  @Test 
   public void postServeiceSuccess () {

mockedAuthServerRestTemplet.expect(requestTo(ACCESS_TOKEN_URI)).andExpect(content().string(requestToAuthServer)).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST)).andRespond(withSuccess("{abc : 'abc'}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

   postMessageService.postMessage(jsonMessage);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the test case and reformat the question so that is clearer? This code is really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an instance of `RestTemplate` but not using it. What is `MockRestServiceServer` doing? 
I can also see a wrong utilisation of `@Resource` and `@Autowired`, which you shouldn't specify in your test. Try use `@MockBean`.

Autowiring works so that the resource you create in your test is injected in the real class, not the other way round.

I'll just add some sample code here, which might help you achieve your goal.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public abstract class AbstractControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    protected Service service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Mockito.reset(service);
    }
}
```

and then your test

```
public class YourTest extends AbstractControllerTest {


@Test
public void shouldDoSomething() throws Exception {

    // given
    List<someStuff> stuff = new ArrayList<>();

    stuff.add(new Whatever("content", "John Smith");

    // when - service is in the abstract controller!
    when(service.getSomething()).thenReturn(stuff);

    // then
    mockMvc.perform(get("/posts/1/whatever").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].content", is("content")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].author", is("John Smith"))));

}
```

Comment: couldn't  make understanding on it, can you please make it more descriptive or look into my edited query again.